Enable runtime UB checks in libstdc++
Is it possible with g++/libstdc++ to enable runtime UB checks, so that for example:

std::vector::operator[] behaves the same as std::vector::at()
std::optional::operator* behaves the same as std::optional::value()

I do not want to detect language level UB (that requires something like ubsan). I just want reasonable "safe" behaviour in the standard library. These should be checks appropriate for production, not ubsan/address-sanitizer.

This question is similar to: Is there a C++ implementation that detects all undefined behavior?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

AFAIK those methods (at() and value()) exists only to give you the bounds checking.

Yes(-ish) to vector if you #define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG. Well it doesn't do exactly the same as at. And I don't see it doing anything for optional.

Can you use the undefined behavior sanitizer?

Formally, undefined behavior isn't a runtime thing. It means only that the C++ standard doesn't tell you what the behavior of your program will be. It does not mean that bad things must happen.

@zerocukor287 that is a different question. It is asking about detecting all UB behaviour. I am only asking about libstdc++, as very clearly stated in the title.

@PeteBecker indeed, but in practice GCC/libstdc++ do cause bad things to happen on UB. That is the whole point of this question. Can I reconfigure libstdc++ so that it doesn't in some common cases at least.

@teapot418 thanks, that looks like a solid bet! I found a page listing all the containers it supports, unfortunately not std::optional as you noted.

Just use address sanitizer and undefined behavior sanitizer: https://godbolt.org/z/11K9T6TK9

@MarekR those are really debugging tools. I want this on permanently. They're also quite annoying to enable in complex projects.

I would [edit] question and mark that this check is required on production.

@Timmmm There seems to be some debug assertion for std::optional::operator* as well, see https://godbolt.org/z/vdT65r97j. This corresponds with the source code, where __glibcxx_assert is used: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/eff7e72815ada5c70c974d42f6a419e29a03eb27/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L1179.

@MarekR It works for std::vector, but not for std::optional: https://godbolt.org/z/q7PW1Ta55.

The [] vs at() isn't particularly UB checking, it's input validation. It seems that's what you want, any kind of input/content/etc validity checks.

@DanielLangr ah that's great, thanks!

@Xellos: using [] with an invalid index leads to UB. I want to prevent UB. If that requires input validation, fine. Let's not argue over semantics.
